# From Puzzling to StackExchange

Tags: optimization, english, word-ladder, pencil-and-paper-games

This is a variation of a game I used to play with my friends in my childhood. You are given a starting word, and using the following operations, you have to reach the target word. The solution that requires the least number of moves wins.

**Rules:**

- In any move, you can either replace a letter, add a letter, remove a letter, split a word or combine two words. These are the five valid moves, and only one of these can be applied in a move.
- After each move, each of the resulting words must be valid by itself, even if it makes no sense as a phrase. **To level the playing field, only words found on Dictionary.com are considered valid.** No proper nouns, abbreviations, prefixes or suffixes allowed. (However, words like jack, john, jane etc. are allowed as they are used as common nouns too.) Alternate spellings and archaic words are permitted, but words referring to specific persons, places or events are not valid.
- You may only add a letter to an existing word, but a new letter (such as a or I) cannot create a new word separately. Likewise, you cannot drop a letter from a one-letter word to remove it altogether.

As an example, consider the following solution where I go from "stack" to "exchange":

stack
stark
star
stay
stray
astray
a stray
as stray
ax stray
ex stray
ex stay
ex star
ex stare
ex share
ex chare
ex charge
ex change
exchange

This solution required 17 moves. (It may not be the optimal strategy for this pair of words, but it is a valid strategy, given just as an example).

**Challenge:**

In how many moves can you get from "Puzzling" to "Stack Exchange"?

**An Extra Twist:**

The solution which achieves this in the least number of moves will be awarded the green tick. However, in the event of a tie, each of the words will be assigned their Scrabble score and then added up. The one with the highest Scrabble score will win.

Comment: The difficulty is to get rid of those damn Z's!

Comment: Can confirm there's at least a 33 step solution.

Comment: a 12-step version of your example is:  stack, stark, shark, sh ark, eh ark, ex ark, ex hark, ex hare, ex chare, ex charge, ex change, exchange

Comment: This is begging for a super computer's bruteforce... If only I had one.

Comment: You forgot a tag, I added it in for you

Comment: Wouldn't "puzzling" (and "muzzling") already have a suffix?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've got 20

> puzzling 
>  muzzling 
>  muzz ling 
>  fuzz ling 
>  fuze ling 
>  faze ling 
>  fake ling 
>  sake ling 
>  saker ling 
>  sacker ling 
>  stacker ling 
>  stack er ling 
>  stack ex ling 
>  stack ex line 
>  stack ex lane 
>  stack ex cane 
>  stack ex care 
>  stack ex chare 
>  stack ex charge 
>  stack ex change 
>  stack exchange

Comment: With the best valid entry thus far, you get the green tick for now although you should protect your answer by maximizing your Scrabble score.

Answer (score 19):

I've done it in 21:

> puzzling
>
> muzzling
>
> muzz ling
>
> muzz line
>
> muzz lane
>
> muzz cane
>
> muzz care
>
> muzz chare
>
> muzz charge
>
> muzz change
>
> fuzz change
>
> fuze change
>
> faze change
>
> fare change
>
> tare change
>
> stare change
>
> starer change
>
> star er change
>
> star ex change
>
> stark ex change
>
> stark exchange
>
> stack exchange

Comment: You can cut some out since "ling" is a word!

Comment: @CodeNewbie Thanks, I've corrected it. Obviously I'm better with words than numbers!

Comment: @GordonK: Nice edit, but e isn't a word. I've tightened rules to avoid abbreviations, prefixes and suffixes. Sorry for this late edit.

Comment: The idea was to keep it restricted to English words (even if they're archaic or alternate spellings). So no, es isn't allowed as it's only defined as a suffix or abbr.

Comment: @CodeNewbie How's that, or is ER disallowed as it's an interjection?

Comment: You could go with fared -> far ed ... 
Ed seen as male name

Comment: er is fine as an interjection. Bravo! A fantastic solution now.

Comment: @WaKai That might be regarded as an abbreviation for Edward, Edgar, Edmond

Comment: Muzz is british slang. It really counts?

Comment: `fuzzling` is also a word. That will save you 1 move as well

Comment: @dberm22 Not according to Dictionary.com and rule 2 specifies that the words must be in there

Comment: @GordonK Fair enough.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it in **20** moves:

> puzzling
> muzzling
> mizzling
> fizzling
> fizz ling
> fizz hing
> fizz hang
> fizz chang
> fizz change
> fuzz change
> fuze change
> faze change
> fare change
> tare change
> stare change
> starer change
> star er change
> star ex change
> stark ex change
> stark exchange
> stack exchange

Comment: Isn't Chang a proper noun?

Comment: @Lampost42 is correct. Chang isn't valid as per the rules. Great try nonetheless

Comment: @CodeNewbie I didn't mean it as a Chinese personal name, but as a name for the river Yangtze (as it's listed at dictionary.com). Does that count as a proper noun?

Comment: Yes, that would be a proper noun. It's specific to the river Yangtze and to no other river.

Answer (score 4):

I did it in **21** moves from `puzzling` to `stack exchange`. But I'm pretty sure there has to be a place to shave off a move.

> puzzling
>
> muzzling
>
> muzz ling
>
> muzz line
>
> muzz lane
>
> muzz laner
>
> muzz langer
>
> muzz hanger
>
> muzz changer
>
> muzz change
>
> fuzz change
>
> fuze change
>
> faze change
>
> fare change
>
> care change
>
> carex change
>
> car ex change
>
> scar ex change
>
> star ex change
>
> stark ex change
>
> stack ex change
>
> stack exchange

Comment: Uhoh, I think it's time to get calculating the Scrabble scores... Good job Raystafarian!

Comment: @CodeNewbie I have to be honest, muzzling hit a double letter and a triple word on my board..

Comment: Isn't Lange a proper noun? Carex is a useful word, though. I missed that one.

Comment: @GordonK yeah, I guess Lange is a proper noun, hmmm. OK replaced lange with laner.

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to this party, and the OP seems to have left, but here's my **19-word** solution! (Basically Lampost's accepted answer with some of the ending changed)

> puzzling
> muzzling
> muzz ling
> fuzz ling
> fuze ling
> faze ling
> fake ling
> sake ling
> saker ling
> sacker ling
> stacker ling
> stack er ling
> stack ex ling
> stack ex line
> stack ex lane
> stack ex lance
> stack ex [hance](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hance?s=t)
> stack ex chance
> stack ex change
> stack exchange

Answer (score 2):

19 moves i think

> 1.puzzling
>  2.muzzling
>  3.muzz ling
>  4.muzz lang
>  5.muzz hang
>  6.muzz chang
>  7.muzz change
>  8.fuzz change
>  9.fuze change
>  10.faze change
>  11.fake change
>  12.flake change
>  13.flaker change
>  14.flak er change
>  15.flak ex change
>  16.flak exchange
>  17.flack exchange
>  18.slack exchange
>  19.stack exchange

Comment: chang is not a valid word according to rule 2.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Bummer :(,

Comment: +1 nonetheless. You should try to find a fix to your answer. Because barring that one word, this answer is rock solid.

Comment: Nice one! I had a solution with "chang" too, but the best I could get was 20 moves.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Are you allowed slang if it is on dictionary.com? Can't see anything in the rules saying you can't ?

Comment: slang is okay. As long as it isn't too specific. Or an informal term for a particular person only.

Answer (score 0):

20 moves

Maybe this answer will give other people some ideas, like Lampost42's gave me

> 0.puzzling
>  1.muzzling
>  2.muzz ling
>  3.muzz sing
>  4.muzz singe
>  5.muzz singed
>  6.muzz hinged
>  7.muzz hanged
>  8.muzz changed
>  9.muzz change
>  10.fuzz change
>  11.fuze change
>  12.faze change
>  13.fake change
>  14.sake change
>  15.saker change
>  16.sacker change
>  17.stacker change
>  18.stack er change
>  19.stack ex change
>  20.stack exchange