# Word ladder island (formerly dead-end)

Tags: word, optimization, english, word-ladder, pencil-and-paper-games

Following on from [CodeNewbie's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12700/codenewbie) question ["From Puzzling to Stack Exchange"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20141/from-puzzling-to-stackexchange), I thought I would set a problem of my own using the same rules:

---

**Rules:**

- In any move, you can either replace a letter, add a letter, remove a letter, split a word or combine two words. These are the five valid moves, and only one of these can be applied in a move.
- After each move, each of the resulting words must be valid by itself, even if it makes no sense as a phrase. **To level the playing field, only words found on Dictionary.com are considered valid.** No proper nouns, abbreviations, prefixes or suffixes allowed. (However, words like jack, john, jane etc. are allowed as they are used as common nouns too.) Alternate spellings and archaic words are permitted, but words referring to specific persons, places or events are not valid.
- You may only add a letter to an existing word, but a new letter (such as a or I) cannot create a new word separately. Likewise, you cannot drop a letter from a one-letter word to remove it altogether.

---

The problem is that two of the words I chose *Perfect* and *Answer* appeared to be word islands. By this I mean that there doesn't appear to be any way to move from those words to any other words following the rules above (except, of course for the trivial case of adding an **S** to the end which doesn't help the transition to anything else).

**Question**

What is the shortest word that anyone can find which is also a word island?
(I'll accept answers where it is one of a pair of words where the only valid moves are back and forwards between them)

Of course, I would be glad to hear if my two examples are not, in fact, islands after all.

Comment: dictionary.com limiter is the mind killer,  searched persect and found this
http://www.speclab.com/compound/c5264553.htm so if ditching the dictionary.com limitation then would perfect still dead-end?

Comment: Where does COBOL fall on the acceptance spectrum. It's on dictionary.com but it's sort of an abbreviation

Comment: Perfect has two words besides adding the 's'. Perfecta and Perfecto are both on Dictionary.com. Perfecta is probably the better choices for creating longer chains, since your second move can be splitting it into "perfect a", but perfecto looks to be a more "legitimate" word.

Comment: @NeedAName if you are suggesting COBOL as a answer, you can drop the B to make cool.

Comment: I'm not, I was looking at OBOE/OBOL

Comment: @VictorHenry you can do perfecto $\rightarrow$ perfect o $\rightarrow$ perfect a

Comment: For the record, I'm using this tool for a lot of this: http://boulter.com/scrabble/

Comment: @VictorHenry So by my definition of a dead end, Perfect isn't a dead end. You still can't get rid of it if you're trying to complete a word ladder though.

Comment: Thought I had another with YACHT, but dictionary.com shows in related forms the word YACHTY in addition to the plural YACHTS(though it redirects to yacht and doesn't show in victor's tool)

Comment: @NeedAName it redirects because the plural form is listed in the same page.

Comment: I need a clarification on your challenge here because I think you're using the wrong term. A "dead end" would be a path that leads to nowhere but where you came from - so a dead end would be a word that has only one possible way to connect it to some other word or pair of words. But the way you're describing it, it seems like you're looking for word islands, or words that can not ever be connected to other words.

Comment: @Kingrames Yes, I suppose word islands would be a better description of what we're trying to find.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That really narrows it down. You can't go lower than 4 I think, because all of the vowel-less words are not dead ends, and that's probably the only way to minimize the number of words that share things in common.

Comment: Ooh is close but it's connected to pooh, aah is cloce but is connected to bah. Looks like all-vowel words just have too many options.

Comment: You can drop the first letter from either of those.

Comment: @NeedAName TWL06 allows obol-oboe-obe (which has many links),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the TWL 2006 wordlist, the shortest isolani (1-word islands) are 4 letters long: `asci enuf lynx pfft sybo`. So it seems to me, too, that CodeNewbie's `lynx` has no links. A further 4-letter word can be transformed only by splitting: `elhi`.

There are also the following 2-word islands which contain words of no more than 4 letters: `zuz-zzz; ebb-ebbs; amok-amoks; iglu-iglus; kufi-kufis; onyx-oryx`. There are also word pairs which would have been 2-word islands except for the splitting option: `exam-exams; isba-isbas; upby-upbye; weka-wekas`.

Using the SOWPODS wordlist, the shortest isolani are 4 letters long: `aesc enuf euoi mwah occy pfft yunx`. A further 4-letter word can be transformed only by splitting: `yebo`.

There are also the following 2-word islands which contain words of no more than 4 letters: `hwyl-hwyls; myxo-myxos; omov-omovs; vuln-vulns; waac-waacs`. There is also a word pair which would have been a 2-word island except for the splitting option: `exam-exams`.

Some examples of SOWPODS neighbours to TWL isolani: `asci-fasci-fasti; lynx-lyne` and beginner 101's `lynx-jynx; sybo-kybo-kobo-kobs`. SOWPODS also has a link from `elhi` other than the split `el hi`: `elchi`.

Wikipedia's pages on [TWL06](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Official_Tournament_and_Club_Word_List#References) and [SOWPODS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOWPODS#References) contain links to the respective complete lists, in .txt form.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. Any chance you can add links to those sources, please?

Comment: Your suggestion of "ebb" is one letter shorter than the previously accepted lynx, so I've given you the tick. zuz-zzz also works, but I personally don't feel that zzz should count as a real word!

Answer (score 6):

A 4 letter word that I found to be a <strike>dead-end</strike> word ladder island

> <strike>`xenon`</strike>  <strike>`vixen`</strike> `lynx`

Why it's a <strike>dead-end</strike> word ladder island

> The plural is `lynxes`, so that isn't a possible move. `ly` is just a suffix, whereas `lyn` is an abbreviation which makes that invalid too. So splitting it is not useful. Trying for replacements gives us `Lynn` and `Lynd` but both are invalid as they are proper nouns.

Comment: xenon -> tenon -> ten on -> tend on -> rend on -> read on -> dead on -> dead an -> dead and -> dead end. Hmm?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Brilliant way to point out my error!:-D

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vimen?s=t :(

Comment: vixen -> vimen => vim en

Comment: dictionary.com cites 'lynix' as 'a misspelling of linux, or possibly lynx'...so I'd wager that doesn't count either.

Comment: @BaileyM I think Linux is a proper noun. And about misspellings, I don't think they can be treated as alternate spellings. Honestly though, this time GordonK makes the rules, so I wonder what he thinks.

Comment: Ah, when I said "that doesn't count", I meant 'lynix' doesn't count as a contradictor. I think you've found a good one here. :D

Comment: @BaileyM, ahh, okay then. Now I'm waiting to see if someone can find a 3 letter word. Although that seems nearly impossible, considering the rules.

Comment: Yes, we may have a winner!

Comment: sorry, but how about jynx at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jynx?s=t

Comment: @beginner101 Nice catch: lynx -> jynx -> jinx -> jin -> tin

Comment: try lisp. It's very close to what you have already.

Comment: I'm not sure if "jynx" should count. Based on the dictionary.com definition, it's not an alternate spelling of "jinx", it's actually the genus name for a type of woodpecker https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wryneck . So should scientific names count for this? Meaning words like "felis" and "canis" would count. It's up to @GordonK I guess.

Comment: @kingrames: list

Comment: @GordonK, does jynx invalidate lynx? If so, I'll change it again.

Comment: It's curious that dictionary.com shows jynx as lower case, but the other genus examples I can find on there are capitalised. Is this a word that was formerly a proper noun, but is now used more generally, such as 'hoover'?

Comment: Given that all the other Genus examples I have looked at are capitalised in dictionary.com, I think that jynx should be disregarded, so I'll accept this answer now.

Comment: Rosie has found the word ebb, so I've given her the tick now.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a step back from the ambitious 4-letter words (though I'm certain there has to be something), I found this among five letters:

> ZEBRA

1. Removals and splitting: I used dictionary.com directly and tried removing each letter and got no legal words. I also tried spliting at every possible joint and got no legal words.
2. Additions: Using [this tool](http://www.visca.com/regexdict/), I searched for words containing a letter added in any spot and got no legal words.
3. Replacements: Using [this tool](http://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=%60zebra&ent=Search&dict=0), I found only two words achieved by replacing a letter:

   > DEBRA and ZABRA

The first is of course a proper noun and the second doesn't appear on dictionary.com

4.But what about the trivial 'S'? According to dictionary.com, the plural does in fact have an s (I've heard it pluralized the same, like moose). But running that through the same gauntlet above, you get similar results (one less result in step 3 even)

I trust these tools are reliable, but if anyone finds something I missed, let me know

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/zebrass?s=t

Comment: Jiggery-pokery I say!! My regex dictionary failed me

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's a 6-letter word, which I checked using this tool:

http://boulter.com/scrabble/

> Sphinx and Sphynx

1. Couldn't find any 5-letter words using the same letters, so that removes deletion.
2. Inserting letters didn't create any new words that I could see (and the plural is -es, not -s, which helps with the trivial case)
3. Checked all cases of replacing letters with blanks, no results
4. Definitely can't split it into two words

Granted, all this was done using the dictionary of the tool, which is not the same as Dictionary.com. I haven't manually checked each possibility with Dictionary.com, but I feel like this is pretty good.

Unfortunately, its longer than "answer". :(